# Redirect www to non-www AND remove index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a router set up that rewrites /index.php/this/that to simply /this/that, using:

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

How can I also redirect www to non-www? I've tried numerous variations of the following, but haven't had success yet:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just place `www` removal code before other rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've tried this as well, and it's still not redirecting www pages.

Comment: I've tested in multiple browsers. It works when I go to http://mywebsite.com, but not http://www.mywebsite.com - I just get a "This webpage is not available" error.

Comment: `This webpage is not available` means `www.mywebsite.com` is not even resolving. You need to allow `www` from Apache config first.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I overlooked the fact that there wasn't a CNAME record in my DNS.